# Nginx Custom Error 403 Page Not Working with IP Deny in new version

Tags: nginx

I deny some country in my server via GEO IP , it work's fine , but i want to show custom 403 page to visitors

i read about this problem in some website like this

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/164595

and i added allow all; tag in end of location , but it's not work !

```
    error_page  403              /403.html;
    location = /403.html {
    root   /home2/site/error;
    allow all;
}
```

but it's not working and i revive default 403 Forbidden page !
please help me how can i solve this problem